# How would a motionless person/object with no gravitational forces acting upon them experience time relative to a person on earth?

Tags: mass, time, time-dilation

Regarding time dilation, how slowly would a theoretically completely stationary person experience time in comparison to those on earth, with that person being infinitely far away from any other object that could cause said person to be affected by a gravitational pull? From what I understand, the more an object travels closer and closer to the speed of light, and the higher the gravitational forces acting upon them, the further time will “slow down” for them from an outside perspective.

We are currently moving through space at roughly 760 miles per second (0.40771% the speed of light) and affected by 1 G of gravitational force, so in essence, my question is “what would happen if one wasnt moving at all and had no gravitation force acting upon them.” Will time go seemingly infinitely fast from and outside perspective for that object/person while everything else doesn’t move at all from an outside perspective? Would its atoms seemingly instantly decay from the perspective of someone on earth? (Obviously if one could observe this theoretical object, they would be close enough to cause gravitational force, but for the sake of argument, let’s ignore this and say we are viewing a simulation of some sort)

Yes, I am aware that due to the expanding nature of the universe and the fact that there is mass inside of it(surprising, i know), one cannot be completely stationary nor can they have no gravitational force acting upon them. And yes, I know that time dilation is all relative and there is no “set” default of the speed at which one experiences time. I just want to know how much time dilation would affect this theoretical person/object in comparison to an object on earth in this hypothetical situation.

Comment: *From what I understand, the more an object travels closer and closer to the speed of light, and the higher the gravitational forces acting upon them, the further time will “slow down” for them from an outside perspective.* Gravitational time dilation does not depend on gravitational force; it depends on gravitational *potential*. For example, if you are at the center of the Earth, there is zero gravitational force but you are in a gravitational potential well and there is a slight time dilation relative to a person on the surface or a person far away in outer space.

Comment: *We are currently moving through space at roughly 760 miles per second (0.40771% the speed of light)*.   Speak for yourself.  I'm standing perfectly still.